# Compton scattering equations

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

In my book, when it discusses Compton Scattering it provides the following momentum equations, where $\gamma$ is Lorentz factor, $m$ is the mass, $u$ is the velocity, $h$ is Plank constant, and $\lambda$ is the wavelength:

---

$$\text{x-component: }\frac{h}{\lambda} = \frac{h}{\lambda'}\cos\theta + \gamma m u\cos\phi$$
$$\text{y-component: }0 = \frac{h}{\lambda'}\sin\theta - \gamma mu\sin\phi.$$

---

However, it does not elaborate on why it divides the equation into an `x-compoenent` and a `y-compoenent`.  What exactly is those two equations telling us in regards to the geometry?

Comment: The fact that we have defined the $x$ direction to be the direction of propagation of the incoming photon (with the $e^{-}$ at rest). If you see, the initial y-momentum = $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this drawing

[image]
<sub>(image from [KJ 3055: X Ray Spectrometry and Radiochemical Methods](http://folk.ntnu.no/floban/KJ%20%203055/X%20%20Ray/Compton%20effect.htm))</sub>

For our convenience we have put the $xyz$ coordinate frame in such a way,
that the $x$-axis is in the direction of the incident photon,
and the scattered electron and photon are moving in the $xy$-plane.

From the drawing above we can read off the various momentum vectors
(each with $x$, $y$ and $z$ component):

- The incident photon has momentum with an $x$ component only:
  $$\vec{p}_{\gamma,\text{incident}}
    =\frac{h}{\lambda}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} \tag{1a}$$
- The initial electron is at rest and therefore has zero momentum:
  $$\vec{p}_{e,\text{initial}}
    =\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} \tag{1b}$$
- The scattered photon has momentum with an $x$ and $y$ component:
  $$\vec{p}_{\gamma,\text{scattered}}
    =\frac{h}{\lambda'}\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta\\\sin\theta\\0\end{pmatrix} \tag{1c}$$
  (Here we used the [geometric definition of $sin$ and $cos$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Right-angled_triangle_definitions).)
- The scattered electron has momentum with an $x$ and $y$ component:
  $\vec{p}_{e,\text{scattered}}
    =\gamma m u\begin{pmatrix}\cos\phi\\-\sin\phi \\0\end{pmatrix} \tag{1d}$
  (Here again we used the geometric definition of $sin$ and $cos$.)

During Compton scattering the total momentum is conserved.
So we have the vector equation:
$$\vec{p}_{\gamma,\text{incident}}   + \vec{p}_{e,\text{initial}} =
  \vec{p}_{\gamma,\text{scattered}} + \vec{p}_{e,\text{scattered}} \tag{2}$$

Plugging in the four momenta from (1a-d) we get
$$\frac{h}{\lambda}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}
 + \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}
 = \frac{h}{\lambda'}\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta\\\sin\theta\\0\end{pmatrix}
 + \gamma m u\begin{pmatrix}\cos\phi\\-\sin\phi\\0\end{pmatrix}
 \tag{3}$$

Writing vector equation (3) in components $(x,y,z)$ we get:
$$\begin{align}
  \frac{h}{\lambda} &= \frac{h}{\lambda'}\cos\theta + \gamma mu\cos\phi \\
  0 &= \frac{h}{\lambda'}\sin\theta - \gamma mu\sin\phi \\
  0 &= 0
\end{align} \tag{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

Momentum is a vector, so 'conservation of momentum' implies 3 equations.

These can be taken along any set of axes you choose. You can call them $x,y,z$ or $e_1,e_2,e_3$, whatever.

However it makes life simple if you choose the $x$ axis to be the initial direction of the photon. And then the $y$ axis to be the orthogonal axis that gives the scattering plane. So, by construction, neither the electron nor the scattered photon has any $z$ component of momentum. The third equation, for $z$, is just $0=0$ which is automatically satisfied and you only have to bother with two.